# Add new record to plone.registry without re-running GenericSetup / re-installing the product

Tags: plone, genericsetup

in a Plone add-on product, I have a control panel page where some config options can be set. They are stored in plone.registry. The control panel adapter fetches the different fields in its `__init__` method by querying the interface, like:

```
class MultiLanguageExtraOptionsAdapter(LanguageControlPanelAdapter):
    implementsOnly(IMultiLanguageExtraOptionsSchema)

    def __init__(self, context):
        super(MultiLanguageExtraOptionsAdapter, self).__init__(context)
        self.registry = getUtility(IRegistry)
        self.settings = self.registry.forInterface(
            IMultiLanguageExtraOptionsSchema)
```

Now I add an additional field to the interface IMultiLanguageExtraOptionsSchema and restart plone. On the control panel page I then an error:

```
KeyError: 'Interface `plone.app.multilingual.interfaces.IMultiLanguageExtraOptionsSchema` defines a field `blah`, for which there is no record.'
```

(This is expected for the `forInterface`method , as described on the plone.registry README. The record is not there.)

Of course, if I add that field via GenericSetup (registry.xml), and I re-install the product / re-run the "Control Panel" step, all is well:

```
<registry>
 <records interface="plone.app.multilingual.interfaces.IMultiLanguageExtraOptionsSchema">
   <value key="blah"></value>
 <records>
<registry>
```

But I don't want to force users to re-install a product, just because there's a new option in the product-specific control panel. So my question: Is there a recommended way for getting a new record for a new field into plone.registry?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you pass False as the second parameter to forInterface:

```
registry.forInterface(IMultiLanguageExtraOptionsSchema, False)
```

then it won't throw an error if fields from the schema are missing from the registry, but will simply return the field's default value.

Comment: Thanks, adding `check=False` works for displaying the control panel. But trying to save (=set a new value) will result in an AttributeError. 
My solution for now: in the set_blah method inside the control panel adapter, I check if the registry already has a record of the name in question, and if not, I create a plone.registry.Record() (as described in the README) and save it with a default value. This happens before the actual setting of the value passed in from the form (`self.setting.blah = value`)

Answer (score 7):

You could try/catch the KeyError and then make sure all registry settings are registered:

```
try:
    self.settings = self.registry.forInterface(IMultiLanguageExtraOptionsSchema)
except KeyError:
    registry = getUtility(IRegistry)
    registry.registerInterface(IMultiLanguageExtraOptionsSchema)
```

I would recommend to write an upgrade step though (which would force your users to reinstall the product of course).

upgrades.py:

```
def update_registry(context):
    registry = getUtility(IRegistry)
    registry.registerInterface(IMultiLanguageExtraOptionsSchema)
```

upgrades.zcml::

```
  <genericsetup:upgradeStep
      source="*"
      destination="1100"
      title="Update plone.app.multilingual setting registry"
      description=""
      profile="plone.app.multilingual:default"
      handler=".upgrades.update_registry"
      />
```

See

https://github.com/collective/collective.mailchimp/blob/master/collective/mailchimp/upgrades.py

and

https://github.com/collective/collective.mailchimp/blob/master/collective/mailchimp/upgrades.zcml

for an example.

Comment: Thanks, I had also thought of an upgrade step, but IMHO from the user's point of view there's not much difference to re-installing. I just remembered the "bad old days" (pre plone.registry) when it was easily possible to add new settings & have them initialized without try/excepts or user interactions.

Comment: +1 for nice answer. @pysailor: Are you referring to skin-folders?

Answer (score 2):

Safe getting settings from registry:

```
def get_registry_settings(interface, name):
    registry = getUtility(IRegistry)
    settings = registry.forInterface(interface, check=False)
    value = getattr(settings, name)
    if value == settings.__schema__[name].missing_value:
        value = settings.__schema__[name].default
    return value
```